# How can I create a button which adds fields to a Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, hotwire-rails, turbo

I have a form in Rails which uses `fields_for` to accept nested attributes:

```
<%= form_with(model: @combat_tracker, url: form_url) do |f| %>
  …
  <%= f.fields_for :zones do |zone| %>
    <div class="zone-field">
      <%= zone.text_field :name %>
      <%= zone.check_box :_destroy %>
      <%= zone.label :_destroy, "Remove zone" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  …
<% end %>
```

Currently this gives me input fields for any existing `zone`s on `@combat_tracker`. I want to add a button that will dynamically add a new `zone-fields` div for a new `zone` to be added when the form is submitted.

I’m using Rails 7 and assume the solution will involve the use of Turbo or possibly Stimulus, but can’t quite figure out the best way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Shameless plug, maybe it'll help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71713303/rails-7-dynamic-nested-forms-with-hotwire-turbo-frames/71715794#71715794. It's a simple set up without js.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need Turbo or Stimulus. Take a look at [cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon), it should do exactly what you're looking for.

Explaining all process here is quite complex for me, but try to follow [this guide](https://linuxtut.com/rails-6-how-to-create-a-dynamic-form-input-screen-using-cocoon-4691a/) if the gem's one is too long.

Comment: Thank you but I'm not using JQuery and would rather avoid additional gems just for this.