# Turbo nested forms, struggling with tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbo

I've successfully been able to implement [this tutorial](https://dev.to/pezza/dynamic-nested-forms-with-turbo-3786) up to a point.

I can get the nested items to appear by saving the parent form and going back to edit, but I am unable to get my Delete or my Add Option button to actually work.

The Delete button doesn't appear to actually do anything and I can't understand the server stream to figure out what it is trying to do.

The Add Option button somehow is returning "unpermitted parameter" for :title, :description, :question_options_attributes error by attempting to create a parent record instead of a child one as it goes up one level in the controller chain to the surveys/questions_controller#create action.

here's what I have so far:

```
class SurveyQuestion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :survey_section
  has_many :question_options
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :question_options, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

class Surveys::QuestionsController < SurveysController
    before_action :get_section, only: [:index, :new, :create, :update, :edit]
    before_action :set_question, only: [:edit, :update]

    ...

    def edit
        @option = @question.options.build
        render partial: "surveys/questions/edit", locals: {q: @question, 
            survey: @survey, section: @section, option: @option}
    end

     private
        def get_section
            @survey = Survey.find_by(slug: params[:survey_slug])
            @section = @survey.sections.find_by(section_number: params[:sec_num])
        end

        def create_params
            params.require(:survey_question).permit(:survey_section_id, :position, :question_type)
        end

        def update_params
            params.require(:survey_question).permit(:survey_setion_id, :position, :question_type, 
                :title, :description, question_options_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :name, 
                    :logic, :sub_logic])
        end
        
        def set_question
            @question = @section.questions.find_by(position: params[:position])
        end
```

In my survey question edit view:

```
%turbo-frame{id: "question_#{q.id}", data: {turbo: {action: "advance"}}}
    = form_with(model: q, url: survey_question_path(survey_slug: survey.slug, position: q.position, sec_num: section.section_number)) do |f|

     ...
      %turbo-frame{id: "options"}
        = f.fields_for :question_options, q.options do |of|
            = render "surveys/questions/options/form", form: of, q: q

    .text-start
        = f.submit "Add Option", formaction: survey_question_option_path(survey_slug: q.survey_section.survey.slug, question_position: q.position, index: q.options.size, sec_num: q.survey_section.section_number), formmethod: :post, formnovalidate: true, id: "add_option"
```

in the surveys/questions/options/form partial:

```
%turbo-frame{id: "question_#{q.id}_option_#{form.index}"}
    = form.hidden_field :id
    %p This is form index number #{form.index}.
    .form-floating.mb-4
        = form.text_field :name, placeholder: "Option #{form.index + 1}", class: "form-control border border-dark"
        = form.label :name, "Option #{form.index + 1}"
    = form.submit "Delete", formaction: survey_question_option_path(survey_slug: q.survey_section.survey.slug, question_position: q.position, index: form.index, id: form.object.id, sec_num: q.survey_section.section_number), formmethod: :delete, formnovalidate: true, data: {turbo: {frame: "question_#{q.id}_option_#{form.index}"}}
```

in the surveys/questions/options/create.turbo_stream.haml:

```
= fields model: @question do |f|
  = f.fields_for :question_options, @options, child_index: params[:index] do |of|
    = turbo_stream.replace "add_option" do
      = f.submit "Add Option", formaction: survey_question_option_path(survey_slug: @survey.slug, question_position: @question.position, index: of.index.to_i + 1, sec_num: @section.section_number), formmethod: :post, formnovalidate: true, id: "add_option"

    = turbo_stream.append "options" do
      = render "surveys/questions/options/form", form: task_form, q: @question
```

in the surveys/questions/options/destroy.turbo_stream.haml partial:

```
= fields model: @question do |f|
    = f.fields_for :question_options, @options, child_index: params[:index] do |of|
        %turbo-frame{id: "question_#{@question.id}_option_#{of.index}"}
            = of.hidden_field :id, value: params[:id]
            = of.hidden_field :_destroy, value: true

= turbo_stream.remove(id: "question_#{@question.id}_option_#{params[:index]}")
```

the options controller:

```
class Surveys::Questions::OptionsController < Surveys::QuestionsController
    before_action :setup

    def new
    end

    def destroy
    end

    private

        def setup
            @survey = Survey.find_by(slug: params[:survey_slug])
            @channel = @survey.channel
            @section = @survey.sections.find_by(section_number: params[:sec_num])
            @question = @section.questions.find_by(position: params[:question_position])
            @options = @question.options
        end

end
```

And finally the relevant routes:

```
   resources :surveys, param: :slug do
      resources :sections, controller: "surveys/sections", param: :sec_num
      resources :questions, controller: "surveys/questions", param: :position do
        resources :options, controller: "surveys/questions/options", only: [], param: :index do
          member do
            delete "(:id)" => "surveys/questions/options#destroy", as: ""
            post "/" => "surveys/questions/options#create"
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: Just a side note but you should probally name that partial `_fields.html.erb` or something similiar as its kind of implied that a partial named form actually contains said form. There are some other issues here like the use of `find_by` instead of `find` which is an invitation for nil errors and slightly excessive deep nesting.

Answer (score 2):

```rb
class Surveys::QuestionsController < SurveysController
...
class Surveys::Questions::OptionsController < Surveys::QuestionsController
```

I'd say this ^ controller centipede is a bad bad idea. Controllers don't need to inherit from each other to represent your routes. That options controller probably does 3 lookups to set the same `@survey` from every `before_action`.

```rb
params.require(:survey_question).permit(:survey_setion_id
#                                                ^^
```

---

You only have 4 resources and it's already confusing, usually that means you're going against the grain, so to speak. For your routes, just use shallow routes. For example, if I want to edit a question I could care less what section it's in. If I care more there is `question.section` association. Pretty sure you can make it work with defaults:

```rb
# config/routes.rb

# NOTE: if you want to give shallow routes a go:
# shallow do

resources :surveys do
  scope module: :surveys do
    resources :sections
    resources :questions do
      scope module: :questions do
        resources :options, only: [:destroy, :create]
      end
    end
  end
end

# end
```

---

I can show you my set up, you can split it into different actions and/or controllers:

```rb
# config/routes.rb
resources :surveys do
  post :new, on: :new  # even this is now optional
end

# db/migrate/20230430072140_create_survey.rb
class CreateSurveyQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :surveys do |t|
      t.string :name
    end
    create_table :survey_sections do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :survey
    end
    create_table :survey_questions do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.references :survey_section
    end
    create_table :options do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :survey_question
    end
  end
end

# app/models/survey.rb
class Survey < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :survey_sections
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :survey_sections, allow_destroy: true
end

# app/models/survey_section.rb
class SurveySection < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :survey_questions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :survey_questions, allow_destroy: true
end

# app/models/survey_question.rb
class SurveyQuestion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :survey_section
  has_many :options
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :options, allow_destroy: true
end

# app/models/option.rb
class Option < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :survey_question
end
```

Form and field partials follow the same pattern, you could even make a helper or another partial out of it:

```rb
# app/views/surveys/_form.html.erb

<%= form_with model: survey do |f| %>
  <%# === SURVEY FIELDS === %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Survey name" %>

  <%# === SECTIONS === %>
  <%= tag.div id: f.field_id(:survey_sections, index: nil), class: "p-4 border-l" do %>
    <%= tag.div "Sections", class: "font-bold text-2xl" %>
    <%= f.fields_for :survey_sections do |ff| %>
      <%= render "survey_section_fields", f: ff %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%# ADD SECTION %>
  <%= link_to "Add section",
    new_survey_path(field_name: f.field_name(:survey_sections, index: nil)),
    class: "text-blue-500 mb-4", data: {turbo_method: :post} %>

  <%= f.submit class: "block my-4 font-bold" %>
<% end %>
```

```rb
# app/views/surveys/_survey_section_fields.html.erb

<%# === SECTION FIELDS === %>
<%= tag.pre f.object_name %>
<%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Section name" %>

<%# === QUESTIONS === %>
<%= tag.div id: f.field_id(:survey_questions, index: nil), class: "p-4 block border-l" do %>
  <%= tag.div "Questions", class: "font-medium text-xl" %>
  <%= f.fields_for :survey_questions do |ff| %>
    <%= render "survey_question_fields", f: ff %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<%# ADD QUESTION %>
<%= link_to "Add question",
  new_survey_path(field_name: f.field_name(:survey_questions, index: nil)),
  class: "text-blue-500 mb-4", data: {turbo_method: :post} %>
```

```rb
# app/views/surveys/_survey_question_fields.html.erb

<%# === QUESTION FIELDS === %>
<%= tag.pre f.object_name %>
<%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: "Question title" %>

<%# === OPTIONS === %>
<%= tag.div id: f.field_id(:options, index: nil), class: "p-4 block border-l" do %>
  <%= tag.div "Options", class: "font-medium" %>
  <%= f.fields_for :options do |ff| %>
    <%= render "option_fields", f: ff %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<%# ADD OPTION %>
<%= link_to "Add option",
  new_survey_path(field_name: f.field_name(:options, index: nil)),
  class: "text-blue-500 mb-4", data: {turbo_method: :post} %>
```

```rb
# app/views/surveys/_option_fields.html.erb

<%# === OPTION FIELDS === %>
<%= tag.pre f.object_name, class: "text-xs" %>
<%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Option name" %>
```

Controller only gets a single `param[:field_name]` which has all the information we need to build the requested fields with the appropriate index and append it to the correct place on the page:

```rb
# v form model              v associations v           make fields for V
"survey[survey_sections_attributes][4][survey_questions_attributes][1][options]"
#                     section index ^                question index ^
```

To get the target for turbo stream use `parameterize` on the `field_name` which will give you the same thing as `f.field_id` in the templates:

```rb
>> "survey[survey_sections_attributes][4][survey_questions_attributes][1][options]".parameterize(separator: "_")
=> "survey_survey_sections_attributes_4_survey_questions_attributes_1_options"
```

```rb
# app/controllers/survey_controller.rb

# GET/POST /surveys/new
def new
  @survey = Survey.new

  if params[:field_name]
    _, *nested_attributes = params[:field_name].split(/\[|\]/).compact_blank
    helpers.fields model: @survey do |form|
      nested_form_builder_for form, nested_attributes do |f|
        render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.append(
          params[:field_name].parameterize(separator: "_"),
          partial: "#{f.object.class.name.underscore}_fields",
          locals: {f:}
        )
      end
    end
  end
end

private

def nested_form_builder_for f, *nested_attributes, &block
  attribute, index = nested_attributes.flatten!.shift(2)
  if attribute.blank?
    yield f
    return
  end
  association = attribute.chomp("_attributes")
  child_index = index || Process.clock_gettime(Process::CLOCK_REALTIME, :millisecond)
  f.fields_for association, association.classify.constantize.new, child_index: do |ff|
    nested_form_builder_for(ff, nested_attributes, &block)
  end
end
```

Works forever:

```rb
{"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "survey"=>
  {"name"=>"",
   "survey_sections_attributes"=>
    {"0"=>
      {"name"=>"section one",
       "survey_questions_attributes"=>
        {"0"=>
          {"title"=>"q1",
           "options_attributes"=>
            {"0"=>{"name"=>"opt1", "id"=>"14"},
             "1"=>{"name"=>"opt3", "id"=>"15"},
             "1682897205190"=>{"name"=>"new option"}},  # new option
           "id"=>"9"},
         "1682897209862"=>                              # new question
          {"title"=>"new question",
           "options_attributes"=>
            {"1682897215265"=>{"name"=>"with new option"}}}},
       "id"=>"7"},
     "1"=>{"name"=>"", "id"=>"8"},
     "1682897196889"=>{"name"=>"new section"}}},        # new section
 "commit"=>"Update Survey",
 "id"=>"2"}
```

---

**Update**

@max it can be done up to a point, eventually the number of combinations just becomes unmanageable, but for simple cases this works:

```rb
def add_section
  helpers.fields Survey.new do |f|
    f.fields_for :sections, SurveySection.new, child_index: Time.now.to_i do |ff|
      render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.append(params[:target], partial: "survey_section_fields", locals: {f: ff})
    end
  end
end

def add_question
  helpers.fields Survey.new do |f|
    f.fields_for :sections, SurveySection.new, child_index: params[:section_index] do |ff|
      ff.fields_for :questions, SurveyQuestion.new, child_index: Time.now.to_i do |fff|
        render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.append(params[:target], partial: "survey_question_fields", locals: {f: fff})
      end
    end
  end
end

def add_option
  helpers.fields Survey.new do |f|
    f.fields_for :survey_sections, SurveySection.new, child_index: params[:section_index] do |ff|
      ff.fields_for :survey_questions, SurveyQuestion.new, child_index: params[:question_index] do |fff|
        fff.fields_for :options, Option.new, child_index: Time.now.to_i do |ffff|
          render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.append(params[:target], partial: "option_fields", locals: {f: ffff})
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This also doesn't work if nested fields are recursive and are not limited in depth. Probably much simpler to just do it with javascript then.

---

For details:
*[Rails 7 Dynamic Nested Forms with hotwire/turbo frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71713303/rails-7-dynamic-nested-forms-with-hotwire-turbo-frames/71715794#71715794)*

Comment: Nesting your controllers in a module isn't a bad idea in general. It's actually a really good way to differentiate between different nested (and non-nested) respresentations of a resource. Where this question goes wrong is the crazy amount of deep nesting as well as the abuse of the scope resolution operator for namespace definition.

Comment: In general I think its preferable to the "param sniffing" approach where you stuff everything into a single controller action with an ever increasing cyclic complexity.

Comment: @max you're right, i meant that controllers inherit from each other. as for params, it's a cyclic action for a cyclic form, complexity doesn't change(?) with more fields - same method call. the only other way i found is to just use javascript for it.

Comment: Ah, yeah I missed the inheritance part. That's sketchy. As for dealing with multiple levels of nested attributes - I tend to think of nested attributes as a dirty hack for moshing a lot of functionality into a single syncronous form. It has it's place but sometimes it's simpler and better to use JS to send individual POST/PATCH/DELETE requests for the nested items. That keeps the logic simpler and you can provide on the fly feedback as the user is creating/updating items.